# Not able to install svn connectors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to configure svn on my eclipse "Luna", for that I have installed "Subversive svn- Team Provider 4.0.0" through Eclipse Market Place. Now I need to manually install svn connectors, for that, I tried to install them through Help->Install New Software option of eclipse.

There I added location as : http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/

Also tried: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/5.0/update-site/

After that, I checked "subversive SVN connectors" checkbox and clicked on next.
On next screen, I get list of 'SVN Installs' below "Will not be intsalled" title.[As shown in attached screenshot]

[image]

So I am not able to install SVN Connectors and not able to communicate with svn repository. I have tried many possible solutions suggested on google.

What exactly I am missing? Any other thing that I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first uninstalled SVN Team provider 4.0.0 and again reinstalled it through eclipse marketplace. Then I tried to install SVN Connectors through "Install new software" using http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/

this time it worked !!